# Setting List<? extends Interface1>

Tags: java, generics

Trying to do something like:

```
public interface Order {      
    public List<? extends OrderItem> getItems();  
    public void setItems(List<? extends OrderItem> items);  
}  

public interface OrderItem {  
  // stuff
}  

public class OrderItemImp implements OrderItem {  
  // stuff for class impl
}  

public class OrderImp implements Order {  
    public List<OrderItemImp> getItems() {  
        return items;  
    }  
    public void setItems(List<OrderItemImp> items) {  
        this.items = items;  

    }  
}
```

Compiler complaining about setItems method. How can I make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Order` interface definition, the methods look like a pair of get/set methods i.e. logically a property. In which case they need to have the same type. You need to tie them together via a named type parameter:

```
public interface Order<T extends OrderItem> {      
    public List<T> getItems();  
    public void setItems(List<T> items);  
}
```

Not entirely sure if this is the right syntax in Java, but basically both methods must end up referring to the exact same type.

Comment: And `public class OrderImp implements Order<OrderItem> {` .

Answer (score -1):

try replacing

```
public void setItems(List<? extends OrderItem> items);
```

with

```
public <T> void setItems(List<T extends OrderItem> items);
```

. This is now a [generic method](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

Comment: And the implementation in `OrderImp` should be `setItems(List<T extends OrderItem>)` as well.  There is no (easy) way to ensure the items are actually `OrderItemImp` and not some other implementation of `OrderItem`.

Comment: Your syntax is not quite right, it should be `public <T extends OrderItem> void setItems(List<T> items);`

Comment: -1 invalid syntax. Also, this change has absolutely no effect